# Detecting socket connection using ZeroMQ STREAM sockets

Tags: zeromq

I am building a new application that receives data from a number of external devices and needs to make it available to a number of different components. ZeroMQ seems purpose-built for the "data bus" aspect of my architecture.

I recently became aware that zmq STREAM sockets can connect to native TCP sockets and send/received messages. Using zmq throughout has a lot of appeal, but I have one problem that I don't know how to get around.

One of my devices needs to be set up. That is, I connect a socket to it, send it some configuration information, then sit back and wait for it to send me data. The device also has a "reset" capability (useful in some contexts), that requires re-sending the configuration information. Doing this depends upon having visibility to the setup/tear-down stage of the socket interface. I need to know when a new connection is established, so I can send the necessary configuration messages.

It seems that zmq is purposely designed to shield me from that knowledge. Is there a way to do what I want? Or should I just use regular sockets for this interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that reading (the right version of) the fine manual can be instructive.

> When a connection is made, a zero-length message will be received by the application. Similarly, when the peer disconnects (or the connection is lost), a zero-length message will be received by the application.

I guess all that remains is to disambiguate between connect and disconnect. Still looking for advice from the community, if others have dealt with this situation before.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your own answer, I would hesitate to rely on that zero length connect/disconnect message as your whole strategy - that seems needlessly fragile.  It's not clear to me from your question which end is persistent and which end needs configuration information, but I expect that one end *knows* it's resetting and reconnecting, and that end *needs* configuration information from the peer, so it should *ask* for it with a message when it needs it, to which the peer responds with the requested information.

If the peer does not yet have the required configuration information before it receives some other message, it could either queue up that work or it could respond back with the need for the config, and then have the rest of the network handle that need appropriately.

You shouldn't need stream/tcp sockets to make that work, it should work with more standard ZMQ socket types, you just need to build the robustness into your application rather than trying to get it for free from TCP/socket actions.

If I've missed your point, and what I'm suggesting won't work for some reason, you will have to give more specific information about your network topology for anyone else to understand what a suitable solution might be.

Comment: thanks, and if my question was not clear enough I apologize. The pieces of my application will use ZMQ throughout. This is an interface point to some external hardware that uses TCP sockets. They expect users of the hardware to code up "connect and initialize". While ZMQ allows integration with TCP sockets, it doesn't well support "connect and initialize". What I found, while it may appear brittle, is at least documented. If there is a better way to support TCP "connect and initialize" semantics, I'm very interested.

Comment: Ah, that helps - you have no control over the behavior of the device. I assume you're `bind`-ing on the stream socket in your application, and treating it as a persistent server rather than actively managing the new connection when it needs to be set up, correct? The device restarts and just knows to set up a TCP connection to your application, and then wait for config, full stop? Can the device cope with receiving anything other than config, or does it gracefully complain if you send it something when it's waiting for config? You may be able to use a heartbeat to check device status.

Comment: No, the device is the server. I `connect` to it. It accepts connections and then the connection must be configured to tell it what data to send. So I need to know when ZMQ makes a new connection.

Comment: I'm still missing something then. Why can't you just send the config when your application makes the connection?

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Doing a ZMQ `connect` does not necessarily make the connection immediately. It waits until the device accepts one (retrying as necessary). And, should the device reset, it will silently reconnect. I need to detect these events to ensure that the device is configured each and every time it is connected to.

Comment: Gotcha. If there's no graceful handling or complaining about receiving data (a heartbeat) from your application when it's missing configuration data, then it looks like your zero-length message is the only solution. Obviously, you'd assume a strict connect/disconnect/connect/disconnect order, but I'd hate to rely on that. I think in your case, if you can reliably track these connect and disconnect events using a more generic TCP socket, that's probably your better choice, and just use ZMQ for everything else.